# Video player that displays frame number

Tags: osx, video-player

I'm looking for a video player for Mac which will display the current frame number. I know I can get this with some math, but would be much easier for my project to see it on the video while playing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/543000/1093575) might help you!

Comment: @csabinho thank you! I was able to find a solution from that response. For my case, using ffmpeg to add frame number was satisfactory. Here is a link for anyone interested in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364861/frame-number-overlay-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case, using ffmpeg to add frame number was satisfactory. Here is a link for anyone interested in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364861/frame-number-overlay-with-ffmpeg